# Better way to find records meeting two different aggregate criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2016

I need to find customers that have a sum of credit transactions greater than or equal to a threshold amount **and** a sum of debit transactions less than or equal to the inverse of that same threshold amount. I also want to return the transactions whose aggregate transaction amount satisfies the credit and debit thresholds. I have come up with two solutions, but I think I might be making things more complicated than necessary.

Here is some simplified sample data...

```
TransactionID  CustomerID  TransactionDate  TransactionType  TransactionAmount
-------------  ----------  ---------------  ---------------  -----------------
1              1           2020-10-01       Credit           10.25
2              1           2020-10-02       Credit           11.50
3              1           2020-10-02       Debit            -13.25
4              2           2020-10-01       Credit           14.22
5              2           2020-10-02       Debit            -50.75
6              2           2020-10-04       Credit           12.85
7              2           2020-10-07       Debit            -4.53
8              3           2020-10-02       Credit           12.85
```

With a threshold amount of $20 **CustomerID 2** is the only customer that meets that threshold for both credits and debits. So here is my expected result...

```
TransactionID  CustomerID  TransactionDate  TransactionType  TransactionAmount
-------------  ----------  ---------------  ---------------  -----------------
4              2           2020-10-01       Credit           14.22
6              2           2020-10-04       Credit           12.85
5              2           2020-10-02       Debit            -50.75
7              2           2020-10-07       Debit            -4.53
```

I have come up with two solutions. I should mention that due to the software in which I ultimately need to embed this query I a cannot use temp tables or table variables.

**Solution #1**

```
SELECT
         txn.TransactionID
       , txn.CustomerID
       , txn.TransactionDate
       , txn.TransactionType
       , txn.TransactionAmount
FROM     Transactions txn
WHERE    EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                             txn1.CustomerID
                           , SUM(txn1.TransactionAmount) AS [TransactionAmoutTotal]
                    FROM     Transactions txn1
                    WHERE    txn1.TransactionType = 'Credit'
                         AND txn1.CustomerID      = txn.CustomerID
                    GROUP BY txn1.CustomerID
                    HAVING   SUM(txn1.TransactionAmount) >= @ThresholdAmount
                )
     AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                             txn2.CustomerID
                           , SUM(txn2.TransactionAmount) AS [TransactionAmoutTotal]
                    FROM     Transactions txn2
                    WHERE    txn2.TransactionType = 'Debit'
                         AND txn2.CustomerID      = txn.CustomerID
                    GROUP BY txn2.CustomerID
                    HAVING   SUM(txn2.TransactionAmount) <= (@ThresholdAmount * -1)
                )
ORDER BY txn.CustomerID
       , txn.TransactionType
       , txn.TransactionDate;
```

**Solution #2**

```
WITH txn_cte (TransactionID, CustomerID, TransactionDate, TransactionType, TransactionAmount, TransactionAmountTotal) AS
(
    SELECT
          txn.TransactionID
        , txn.CustomerID
        , txn.TransactionDate
        , txn.TransactionType
        , txn.TransactionAmount
        , txn.TransactionAmountTotal
    FROM  (
              SELECT
                   TransactionID
                 , CustomerID
                 , TransactionDate
                 , TransactionType
                 , TransactionAmount
                 , SUM(TransactionAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, TransactionType) AS [TransactionAmountTotal]
              FROM Transactions
          ) txn
    WHERE ABS(txn.TransactionAmountTotal) >= @ThresholdAmount
)
SELECT
         txn_cte.TransactionID
       , txn_cte.CustomerID
       , txn_cte.TransactionDate
       , txn_cte.TransactionType
       , txn_cte.TransactionAmount
FROM     txn_cte
WHERE    EXISTS (
                    SELECT txn_cte1.TransactionID
                    FROM   txn_cte txn_cte1
                    WHERE  txn_cte1.TransactionType        = 'Credit'
                       AND txn_cte1.CustomerID             = txn_cte.CustomerID
                )
     AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT txn_cte2.TransactionID
                    FROM   txn_cte txn_cte2
                    WHERE  txn_cte2.TransactionType        = 'Debit'
                       AND txn_cte2.CustomerID             = txn_cte.CustomerID
                )
ORDER BY txn_cte.CustomerID
       , txn_cte.TransactionType
       , txn_cte.TransactionDate;
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=199519521a2a690b0f8a88194f62dc11) of my sample data inserts and two solutions. Is there a better way to do this given I cannot use temp tables or table variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select transactionid, customerid, transactiondate, transactiontype, transactionamount
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when transactiontype = 'Credit' then transactionamount else 0 end) 
            over(partition by customerid) sum_credit,
        sum(case when transactiontype = 'Debit' then transactionamount else 0 end) 
            over(partition by customerid) sum_debit
    from transactions t
) t
where sum_credit > @ThresholdAmount and sum_debit < - @ThresholdAmount
order by customerid, transactiontype, transactiondate
```

Within the subquery, the conditional sums compute the total debit and credit of each customer. You can then use this information for filtering in the outer query.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps some conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` is what you are after? Though this returns no rows, as no customers have a *"sum of credit transactions greater than a threshold amount and a sum of debit transactions greater than that same threshold amount"*. That is because all the debit transactions have a negative value, and the `SUM` of negative values can never be positive (and thus could never be greater than the value of `20` you have in your example):

```sql
DECLARE @ThresholdAmount NUMERIC(10, 2);
SET @ThresholdAmount = 20.00;

SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING SUM(CASE TransactionType WHEN 'Credit' THEN TransactionAmount END) > @ThresholdAmount
   AND SUM(CASE TransactionType WHEN 'Debit' THEN TransactionAmount END) > @ThresholdAmount;
```

Comment: I need to clarify the requirement. Given a threshold amount of $20 I am looking for customers with a sum of credit transactions greater than or equal to that threshold amount **and** a sum of debit transaction less than or equal to the inverse of that threshold amount. So if a customer has -$30 in debit transaction I would say they meet the threshold. If I change the last part of your HAVING clause to `< (@ThresholdAmount * -1)` I do get Customer ID 2. I apologize for the inaccurate requirement. I was thinking in business terms rather than technical terms.